# Show TR using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html-table

I am using jquery to show TR in TABLE as the following :

All table loaded than by using JSTL I hide certain TR than show these TR using link click. 
For example

row 0 visible and has a link:
   row 1 invisible under row 0 , when user click on row 0 link row 1 become visible.

but when I click on this link row 1 appear but under row 0 TD.

Here is my Jquery:

```
function expand_ClickEvent(rowData){

           //get the TR that you want to show/hide
           var _TR = $("#tr_0");
           var TR = $("#tr_1");
           //check its class
           if (TR.hasClass('hide')){
              TR.removeClass('hide'); //remove the hide class
              TR.addClass('show');    //change it to the show class
              TR.insertAfter(_TR);
              //TR.show();              //show the TR (you can use any jquery animation)

           } else {
              TR.removeClass('show'); //remove the show class
              TR.addClass('hide');    //change it to the hide class
              TR.hide();              //hide the TR (you can use any jquery animation)

           }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `html` already contains thesecond  `tr`, you shouldn't be inserting it again.
And also use the `toggle` function.
Your code will be just the one line:

```
$("#tr_1").toggle();
```

Comment: Not working , I can't understand why:
<code>
if (TR.hasClass('hide')){
         TR.removeClass('hide'); //remove the hide class
         TR.addClass('show');    //change it to the show class
         //TR.show();              //show the TR (you can use any jquery animation)
         TR.toggle();
    
      }
</code>

Comment: @Sherif ?? what do you mean? Could you update your question with the corresponding `html` code.